# How to detect a click or mouse press on IE with Raphael and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, raphael, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Raphaeljs and Internet Explorer, problem when clicking an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873777/raphaeljs-and-internet-explorer-problem-when-clicking-an-element)

I'm trying to find a way to trigger an event when a mouse clicks on some text generated from Raphael JS. In Firefox, the click event works perfectly, in IE 7 and 8 (I haven't tested earlier versions) neither click nor mousedown work. Click works fine for other raphael objects, e.g. the rectangle in the example.

How can I trigger an event on the text given in the demonstration below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael-min.js?raw=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div id="graph"></div>
    
    <script language="javascript">
        function setupImage() {
            var canvas = Raphael(graph, 200, 200);
    
            var alpha = canvas.text(100, 10, "Two Words");
            alpha.attr("font-size", "20px");
    
            var beta = canvas.rect(50, 50, 50, 50);
            beta.attr("fill", "#3333cc");
    
            canvas.safari();
    
            var textClickEvent = function(event) {
                alert("text clicked");
            };
    
            var boxClickEvent = function(event) {
                alert("box clicked");
            }; 
    
            $(alpha.node).click(textClickEvent);
            $(beta.node).click(boxClickEvent);
        }
    
        $(window).load(setupImage);
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

My gut feeling is I may have to try manipulate the DOM to wrap the text in, e.g., an A element and bind on that instead. That doesn't seem like the cleanest solution so I'm asking here to see if anyone has an alternative approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use the raphael built in event coding like this:

```
alpha.node.onclick = textClickEvent;
beta.node.onclick = boxClickEvent;
```

or you could also do this:

```
alpha.click(textClickEvent);
beta.click(boxClickEvent);
```

The rest of your code is fine.

Some helpful links: [Raphael events section](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#events) and [Raphael node section](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#node).

Comment: Thanks, the alpha.click(textClickEvent) worked perfectly. I was previously trying to alpha.node.onclick = textClickEvent but that doesn't work in IE. Great, no need for jQuery! Cheers again.