# Raphaeljs and Internet Explorer, problem when clicking an element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, raphael, vml

I have the following piece of code in javascript that basically hide or show a Raphaeljs set when I click on it. It works perfectly well under Google Chrome, FireFox and Safari, but not at all under Internet Explorer.

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('ADiv'), 450, 490);

var group = paper.set();

var toxicRect = paper.rect(0, 0, 120, 60, 10 );
toxicRect.attr({"stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke" : "#3083BE",
            "fill" : "#D1DFE9"});

group.push( toxicRect );

var toxicRectText = paper.text(60, 25, "Toxic in air\nthrough inhalation");
toxicRectText.attr({"font-size": 12 });
group.push( toxicRectText );

var toxicToConcentrationPath = paper.path("M60 60L60 80")
toxicToConcentrationPath.attr({"stroke-width": 1,
                   "stroke" : "#3083BE"});

group.push( toxicToConcentrationPath );

var concentrationRect = paper.rect(0, 80, 120, 60, 10 );
concentrationRect.attr({"stroke-width": 1,
                    "stroke" : "#3083BE",
                "fill" : "#D1DFE9"});

group.push(concentrationRect);

var conRectText = paper.text( 60, 105, "Is concentration\n> TLV/TWA");
conRectText.attr({"font-size": 12});
group.push(conRectText);

var conRectTextYes = paper.text(50, 135, "Yes  / ");

conRectTextYes.attr({"font-size": 12,
                 "font-style": "italic"});

group.push(conRectTextYes);

var conRectTextNo = paper.text(75, 135, "No");
conRectTextNo.attr({"font-size": 12,
                "font-style": "italic"});

group.push(conRectTextNo); 

var monitorConcentrationGroup = paper.set();

var monitorConcentrationRect = paper.rect(140, 95, 60, 30, 10 );
monitorConcentrationRect.attr({"stroke-width": 1,
                        "stroke" : "#3083BE",
                    "fill" : "#D1DFE9"});

monitorConcentrationGroup.push(monitorConcentrationRect);

var monitorConcentrationRectText =  paper.text(170, 115, "Monitor");
monitorConcentrationRectText.attr({"font-size": 12});

monitorConcentrationGroup.push(monitorConcentrationRectText);

var concentrationToMonitorPath = paper.path("M120 110L140 110")
concentrationToMonitorPath.attr({"stroke-width": 1,
                     "stroke" : "#3083BE"});

monitorConcentrationGroup.push(concentrationToMonitorPath);
monitorConcentrationGroup.hide();


//Actions when clicking on decisions
conRectTextYes.node.onclick = function () {

        monitorConcentrationGroup.hide();
};

conRectTextNo.node.onclick = function () {

        monitorConcentrationGroup.show();
};
```

Anyone has any ideas? You can test it at http://raphaeljs.com/playground.html by making a cut and paste and omitting the first line of the script. Clicking the "No" should make a box appears, at least in Chrome, but not in IE...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Raphael uses VML to render shapes in IE8, specifically the VML `textpath` element in your example. However, IE8 does not fire mouse events for that element. You could go up the node tree and attach your event handler to the `shape` element that contains the `textpath` but, even then, the active-area only consists of the pixels that make up the text, so it's very difficult to click.

A better solution would be to add a transparent rectangle behind the text and attach your event handler to that as well:

```
...

// Make the rectangle slightly larger and offset it 
// from the text coordinates so that it covers the text.
var conRectTextNoContainer = paper.rect(75 - 8, 135 - 9, 17, 14);
// Give the rectangle a fill (any color will do) and 
// set its opacity to and stroke-width to make it invisible
conRectTextNoContainer.attr({
  fill: '#000000',
  'fill-opacity': 0,
  'stroke-width': 0
});
group.push(conRectTextNoContainer); 

var conRectTextNo = paper.text(75, 135, "No");
conRectTextNo.attr({
  "font-size": 12,
  "font-style": "italic"
});
group.push(conRectTextNo); 

...

var conRectTextNoNode = conRectTextNo.node;
if (conRectTextNoNode.tagName === 'textpath') {
  // We're in IE8, attach the handler to the parentNode
  conRectTextNoNode = conRectTextNo.node.parentNode;
}
conRectTextNoContainer.node.onclick = (
  conRectTextNoNode.onclick = function () {
    monitorConcentrationGroup.show();
  }
);

...
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/8CZ8G/show/ (Editable via: http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/8CZ8G/)

Answer (score 3):

roughly similar to another question and I will post the same answer:

onmousedown worked for me in IE 7,8, and 9

```
            st[0].onclick = function () {
                myFunc(dataObj);
                st.toFront();
                R.safari();
            };
            st[0].onmousedown = function () {
                myFunc(dataObj);
                st.toFront();
                R.safari();
            };
```

I tried some other methods as well, abstracting the function to a variable but it didnt work. In my case I cannot add a rectangle to the display and have people click on this, it was a poor solution for several reasons.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This actually worked for me. Only had this issue with IE8.  IE9 works well with the click event, whereas IE8 not always.